# How to stop a program from popping up notifications in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I need to turn off the notifications from one of the programs I am using on my Windows 10.

It is not an app that is downloaded from Windows Store so I (think) this is why I cannot remove it via the notifications settings within the Windows (because it doesn't show there).

How can I do that?

The app name is Follow Liker (instagram edition)

Comment: Are you sure it isn't in the notifications settings? I though that was mandatory for anything accessing the notifications feature. What program is that? And have you already checked if it's possible to enable/disable notifications in that program's settings?

Comment: What do you mean it isn't an application?  Please edit your question to clarify that part of your question.

Comment: @Ramhound, "app" is newspeak for Metro application.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Metro applications are Windows 8.x, not Windows 10.  Universal Windows Platform (UWP) application would be Windows 10.  The author should clarify what they mean.  Even your answer applies to all applications, so I am not entirely sure I agree with your "newspeak" definition.

Comment: fixed everything you noted. Kindly find me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look farther down the *Notifications and actions* Control Panel -- [other senders are shown,](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-turn-off-notifications-in-windows-10/) in addition to the "Metro apps". For finer granularity, click on an application. You can also turn off all "notifications from apps and other senders." However, "Some senders might have their own notification settings." Without knowing the application, it's difficult to know.

[image: Notifications and actions]

Comment: Hi MrMoishe,

I didn't find it there as I mentioned in the question. I am skeptic about two options where the program name is "Security and Maintenance", maybe one of them is coincidentally called that by the owners of that program?